# Нужно ли выделять запятыми оборот- для согласования

Tags: пунктуация

Направить график для согласования подписанный со стороны подрядной организации.

Answer (score 3):

В этом предложении нужно сделать перестановку:

*Направить для согласования график, **подписанный со стороны подрядной организации.***

Причастный оборот обособляется в позиции после определяемого слова.